# Issues if Requests.get - 403 Forbidden Error

Tags: python, python-requests, get

```
import requests

headers = {
          'authority': 'tvc4.investing.com',
    'accept': '*/*',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'content-type': 'text/plain',
    'origin': 'https://tvc-invdn-com.investing.com',
    'referer': 'https://tvc-invdn-com.investing.com/',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="116", "Not)A;Brand";v="24", "Google Chrome";v="116"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}

params = {
    'symbol': '17940',
    'resolution': '1',
    'from': '1694613203',
    'to': '1694699663',
}

response = requests.get(
    'https://tvc4.investing.com/86fd2cdaadcb4c77ffd862dcab14c196/1694699591/56/56/23/history',
    params=params,
    headers=headers,
)

print(response.status_code)
```

The above code utilizes requests module from python to get access to the historical data of NIFTY50. The details (url+params) when entered on web browser gives access to the data, but the same does not happen via the script wherein it is facing 403 Forbidden Error. The same issue is faced when the query is copied as curl(bash) and inputted in postman. Is there any way around it? Is it because of JSON Web Token? Do I have to necessarily then use Selenium for simulating web browser and retrieving data via it? Kindly give your suggestions and opinions.

P.S. It has only been less than six months for me within this field. So please bear with me. Thank you!

I really do not know much to be really able to address the issue encountered here.

Comment: You probably have to provide the authentication parameters with auth method, username, and password. Check here : https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/authentication/

Comment: There are no authentication parameters required on the website. Even after creating an account and passing the same info to the requests.get, the same issue is encountered,

Comment: when i type the url you gave into my webbrowser i get a message:
["from field is required","from field must be an integer","to field is required","to field must be an integer"]
So there are probably some missing parameters in the url ? or cookie ?
Could you provide a working url even if you use/do it "by hand" ?

Comment: https://tvc4.investing.com/32241e74eb68fc67222b52ae0b880dad/1695197324/56/56/23/history?symbol=17940&resolution=1&from=1695110932&to=1695197392
This is the complete link with params integrated within it.

Comment: I have been able to download the data via Selenium and activating driver. Nonetheless, here is the link that you have requested.
https://tvc4.investing.com/9dfc1e717c0396b76bbc6b0edc7200bb/1695271205/56/56/23/history?symbol=17940&resolution=1&from=1695186747&to=1695273207